# Something wrong with the root shell

Tags: command-line, root

Today, I've tried opening a root shell and, oh surprise, weird answer...

[image]

Any idea of where it could be from ?

Comment: It is from shell helpers tog it:) We ned a bit more information about how these were installed, there are several bash git completion setups, and shell prompts. However the key point is that they should not have been installed as root - look in /etc/profiles and similar

Answer (score 1):

It seems you set up some sort of git info function to be included in your bash shell. This function now can not be found. Did you update your profile / shell?